# Problems with AWK and power of (DD-WRT)

Tags: math, awk, grep, dd-wrt

I'm trying to extract the sum of numbers to a variable (cwr) in a file (wa_cidr) using this command:

```
cwr=$(grep -E "^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?$" /tmp/wa_cidr | awk -F '/' '`{n += 2**(32 - $NF)}` END {print n}')
```

However, the output is empty.

If I change the part...

```
{n += 2**(32 - $NF)}
```

To...

```
{n += (32 - $NF)}
```

I get a valid result written to the cwr variable.

It would seem that I cannot do the power of (32 - $NF) using either 2**X or 2^X in AWK.

If I do it on the command line, e.g. using...

```
$ echo $(2**5)
```

There's no problem and the result is 32.

I have tried many variations on the formula (parantheses etc.) but nothing seems to Work.

What is wrong? Can it be done in another way?

Thanks,
Søren

Comment: Please show us a sample input line that produces the symptom you describe.

Comment: Also, I assume you meant `awk 'BEGIN { print 2**5  }'` as an interactive test (in the _shell_, you'd have to do `echo $((2**5))` (`$((...))` for arithmetic expansions), but that's not relevant here, given that your problem is with an _Awk_ script).

Comment: I'd be interested to know why you're doing "power of" on a DD-WRT box ? Thanks for sharing (if you can). Solution below is most certainly correct. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - see below and here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=1051848

Comment: @mklement0 - this line

´grep -E "^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?$" /tmp/wa_cidr | awk -F '/' '{n += (32 - $NF)} END {print n}'`
gives the output '524', but this line

`grep -E "^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?$" /tmp/wa_cidr | awk -F '/' '{n += 2^(32 - $NF)} END {print n}'`
gives an empty output.

Even if 32 - $NF is zero (cannot be negative) the result would be 1.

Maybe I need a command parameter to activate "advanced" calculations or something?

Comment: By the way - doing the exact same calculation in Excel gives the output 524 before power of and 3996 after - sum of `(32-$NF)` = 524 / sum of  `2^(32-$NF)` = 3996...

Comment: Doe a _single_ calculation fail? Please add any clarifications - and, ideally, sample input that demonstrates the problem _directly to your answer_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regexp is correct then this would be the correct syntax to do what you appear to be trying to do:

```
cwr=$(awk -F'/' '/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?$/{n += 2^(32 - $NF)} END {print n+0}' /tmp/wa_cidr)
```

Comment: Hmm that do seems like the way to go, but I get this error:

`Stopped (tty input)`

I think there may be some limitations in the DD-WRT shell but I'm at a loss as to why a simple calculation would cause problems.

To clarify: I'm trying to extract CIDR's from the file wa_cidr, get the number after the slash (e.g. IP/30), calculate numbers of IP's in that segment and return the result to $cwr.

Thís works with my command - except - I cannot do the proper calculation (power of) with that number.

I do see your code is better but now I get this error...?

Thanks,
Søren

Comment: It was a typo, I'd put the file name after the last `)` instead of before it. Fixed now. That's one reason it's in your best interests to always provide testable sample input/output when you post a question (i.e. a [mcve]) because without it we can't test a potential solution before posting it.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, it would appear that I was on to something, when I mentioned that something was limited in the DD-WRT Shell.

According to this website, https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Exponentiation_operator#awk, the "traditional awk implementations do not provide an exponent operator, so we define a function to calculate the exponent".

So for the code to Work it needs to look something like this:

```
cwr=$(grep -E "^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))?$" /tmp/wa_cidr | awk -F '/' 'function pow(x,n){r=1;for(i=0;i<n;i++)r=r*x;return r}{c += pow(2,(32-$NF))} END {print c}')
```

Which gives the correct value of 3996.

Thank you all for inputs!

/Søren